# How to create particle system with the original objects color values?

Tags: python, particles

How to create particle system with the original objects color values?
bpy.data.objects['some_object'].color

[image]

Update:
as it seem like, it will work only if the object color
will be copy to all vertices vertex corner attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Particle system does not support object color attribute.
Instead,
I copied the color value to all of the object face corners attributes.

```
obj.data.attributes.new(attribute_name, 'FLOAT_COLOR', 'CORNER')
data = color*loops_num
obj.data.attributes['color'].data.foreach_set('color', data)
```